# how to add close button to top right to cardview in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, cardview

**HOw to Add close button to top right to cardview in android.**
like this:
[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zGlw.jpg)
i want to place my close button to the top right corner of the dialog so that the when button clicked thi will set the visibilty of cardview to gone.  any better method to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create popup with top-right outside close button using below code snippet:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_10"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_20"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim_10"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_20">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_25"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/dim_5"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dim_18"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dim_5"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dim_40">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text_description"
                android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_24"/>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|top"
        android:background="@color/color_black"
        android:padding="@dimen/dim_5"
        android:src="@drawable/close_popup" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using FrameLayout u can achieve that by adjusting the margins for the Close button view